# How to create an image from scanning photographic film?

Tags: windows, scanning

I scanned a film and now I have a brown jpeg. Is there any software to convert the image to a real photo? Or how can I scan a film and get the photos?

Comment: What's a 'real photo'? Do you mean it's come out in negative? Or in one-tone sepia?

Comment: i scanned the film with the original software (EPSON) and it came out in one-tone sepia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, this is done during the scan and not afterwards. Nearly every scanner software has the option to select to scan negatives.

Alternatively, you could try to invert the negative and then use color-correction on it (a photo negative is not an exact inversion of the image).

Comment: i inverted the colors, used auto-level (color-correction). Now the colors are almost ok, but the image is 423x327 pixels and it looks dusty and verry bad if i resize it

Comment: you can't get more out than you put in upfront. Low res to Highres conversion while adding detail on works in TV :-)
Use a highres image to convert and keep that resolution. Just do the lowres for checking your settings to preserve time/interactiviy

Comment: @Jumpy: Wait, you mean we can't extract the license plate from a car a half mile away on the MPEG-distorted 640x480 video? ;) --- @Remus: Jumpy is right...scan it in a higher resolution.

Comment: In CSI they can! They have better software then you do ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want good quality images from negative films, you need a film scanner (e.g. [Nikon Coolscan](http://imaging.nikon.com/products/imaging/lineup/scanner/index.htm)).

For the software part, Adobe Photoshop is able to invert negative and remove orange dominant color.